# issue in the returned value of exectuteUpdate in java,

Tags: java, jdbc

`"UserName"` is a primary key in sql table (so we can't have two users with the same UserName) , When i insert a new value (doesn't exist in the table ) in the user table i have `row = 1` and the message "inserted with succes ! `row =1`" appears , but when the value to insert is already exist in the user table i doesn't get the message (neither the redirection ).
here is the code :

```
String Query = "insert into user values ( '"+ UserName +"', '"+PassWord +"', '"+ mobile +"' ) ;" ;

statm = Cnx.GetConnexion().createStatement();
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
int row = statm.executeUpdate(Query); 

if( row > 0 ) // insertion with succes
{
    pw.println("inserted with succes ! row =" +row);
    //response.sendRedirect("index.html");     
}
else
{
    pw.println("User Name taken ! please try an other one");
    //response.sendRedirect("singup.html");                                                         
}
```

Comment: Do you get any exception in the console or share the stack trace. It may be helpful.

Comment: You're probably getting an sql exception during `executeUpdate`. You need to deal with that or check for existing entries first.

Comment: yes i got a message when i try to insert Jean as UserName that exist already , " Duplicate entry 'Jean' for key 'PRIMARY' " , so i need to know how to handle this exeption inside the try to display it in a normal msg by pw or response.sendreqirect

Answer (score 0):

I guess the code throws an exception. Try this, what happend?

```
try{
    // your code
} catch (Exception e) {
   System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: How about using pw.println instead of System.out.println ?

Comment: Same thing, even wosre , you can't use "pw" in the catch statement !

Comment: Do you initiate pw inside try bracket? Can you share your current code?

Comment: ooooh yeh, i forgote, i initiate pw inside the try bracket , i move it out now to be able to use it inside the catch statement, and i get a message " Duplicate entry 'Jean' for key 'PRIMARY' " , so it worked but we dont know how to get this exeption inside the try to display it in a normal msg by pw !